# How to vertical align elements cross-browser?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, vertical-alignment

I am doing vertical alignment using `vertical-align: middle` property its working in Chrome but not in IE.

Comment: What version of IE? Can you post the relevant HTML and CSS code?

Comment: .login_sign_up_text_box_td
{
 font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:18px;
 color:#000;
 vertical-align:middle;
 height:40px;
 width:200px;

}
i am ujsing IE 7

Comment: Is there any other CSS properties in your stylesheet that are conflicting with this property?

Comment: Without the complete markup or a link, anything we say is just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried flexbox? It's what I use and I haven't had many (if any) compatibility issues, IE can be a little finicky but it definitely supports it.

To center items, you set the container of the elements to `display: flex;` and also add `align-items: center;` to center them vertically within the container. You can also center them horizontally with `justify-content: center;`

You can see it's widely supported here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

[Supposedly](http://www.htmlpedia.org/wiki/Vertical-align), IE8+ supports `vertical-align` but IE7- support is buggy. For older browsers, you may want to try setting the element's container's CSS to `top: 50%` or `top: -50%`.

Comment: It would be nice if drive-by down-voters would leave a comment and explain themselves.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to place a one line text, for example a header title in your box, than use `line-height`

For example with a 200px width and 40px height box:

```
.the_box{
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
}
```

It's easy, elegant, and cross-browser. If you have longer text than 200px, this method will not work.

Answer (score -3):

Simply add this:
`display: table-cell;`

Answer (score -4):

Put

```
style="valign:middle; vertical-align:middle;"
```

Newer versions of IE will pick `valign:middle` and ignore `vertical-align:middle`.

All other browsers like Firefox, Chrome, Safari etc. will pick `vertical-align:middle` and ignore `valign:middle`.

Answer (score -4):

I also had this problem, with a calendar table a colleague of mine created. The Calendar viewed nicely in Chrome, Firefox, but the date text was half cut off in the top left corner of each day. I removed the vertical-alignment property and replaced it with position. See below.

Original CSS:

```
.dayText {
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

My CSS Fix:

```
.dayText {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    height: inherit; 
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I had a similar problem

I had the following

```
<div>
  <span> some text </span>
</div>
```

This was all in a header of a table.

I was able to get around this issue by adding the following to the span

```
<div>
  <span style="position: absolute; padding-top:1px;"> some text </span>
</div>
```